# Could not access the MCR component cache

Tags: matlab, webserver, cgi

I want to use CGI and Apache web server to give users access to run my compiled Matlab application (an exe file). I followed the instructions at [this guide](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-30REEY/).

But, I received an error in the web server logs as:

**[error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not access the MCR component cache., referer: .../standalone.html**

I am using Matlab 2012a. Is there anyway to control the MCR cache for applications compiled using Matlab 2012a? There is no more CTF file with the compilations of this Matlab release.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that in recent versions of MATLAB Compiler the CTF archive is embedded in the .exe by default, but that you can change that back, either by selecting an option from within the `deploytool` settings, or by using the `-C` parameter with `mcc`.

The CTF archive would normally expand automatically the first time you run the component, but if you need to manually expand it (I believe there are reasons you need to when calling it from CGI, although I've never done it myself) there's a utility called `extractCTF.exe` in `matlabroot\toolbox\compiler\arch`, where `arch` is your OS type, such as `win32` etc.

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/deploying-to-end-users.html?searchHighlight=extractctf) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/mcr-component-cache-and-ctf-archive-embedding.html) for more information.

Hope that helps!